# How to automatically play an audio file when a widget is displayed

Tags: flutter

I am displaying a `StatefulWidget` that contains text. I have an mp3 asset file with the narration of that text.

I can play that file in response to a user action, but how can I play the file (in essence call any function) when the widget is initially displayed?

Following advice in comments I tried to play the sound in `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio('audio/narration.mp3'));
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  }
```

However, this raised an error:
`Error: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Comment: Do it in `initState`.

Comment: attempting to `play()` the file in `initState` raises:
```Error: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.```

Comment: What are you using to play mp3s

Comment: can you add some code so that  we can tell you where you are going wrong and what to do. From my thinking the error is because it is not getting the audio file to play.. Still you add some code so that it can be helpful.

Comment: the `initState` code is:
```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio('audio/narration.mp3'));
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  }

```